# Add a single point to legend from geom_point and scale_fill_gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Has been now a few months I am working with `ggplot2` but I still get stuck very easily on basic things, as the options out here are close to infinite.

Let's assume I have a simple plot created as follows:

```
set.seed(100)
df_1 = data.frame(lat = rnorm(20), 
                  lon = rnorm(20), 
                  x = rnorm(20))


library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot() +

    geom_point(data = df_1, 
           aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill = x), 
           size = 5, colour = 'black', pch = 21) +

    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = 'white', high = "yellow",
                         breaks = c(-1, 0, 1), 
                         labels = c('-1', '0', '1'),
                         limits = c(-1,1))

print(p)
```

[image]

How can I add a second legend with title (e.g. y) showing only one of those circles with white background and black contour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add extra element to legend, you have to add it to a plot. You can do this with:

```
geom_point(aes(alpha = ""), head(df_1, 1),
           size = 5, fill = "white", pch = 21) +
```

Here we are adding first point in your dataset, setting it's `fill` and dummy `alpha` value (we need to set something within `aes` to add it to legend). I'm using `""` so we won't have any text next to a point.
Also, it's important to add this point before main `geom_point` because it will cover original point (with white fill). You also need to reset `alpha` values from `""` to `1` and to set wanted legend name for `alpha` in `labs()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_1, aes(lon, lat, fill = x)) +
    geom_point(aes(alpha = ""), head(df_1, 1),
               size = 5, fill = "white", pch = 21) +
    geom_point(size = 5, pch = 21) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "white", high = "yellow",
                         breaks = c(-1, 0, 1), 
                         labels = c("-1", "0", "1"),
                         limits = c(-1, 1)) +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = 1) +
    labs(alpha = "y")
```

[image]

---

PS. I have made some changes in your `ggplot2` code:

- You can specify data and `aes` within first `ggplot` call.
- In geom layers `aes` is first argument, data is second. So instead of `geom_point(data = df_1, aes(...)`. You have use `geom_point(aes(...), df_1)`.
- `color = "black"` is a default setting - you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a factor with one level and use `scale_color_manual`:

```
set.seed(100)
df_1 = data.frame(lat = rnorm(20), 
                  lon = rnorm(20), 
                  x = rnorm(20),
                  new = rep('Coordinates', 20))


library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot() +

  geom_point(data = df_1, 
             aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill = x, colour = new), 
             size = 5, pch = 21) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = 'white', high = "yellow",
                       breaks = c(-1, 0, 1), 
                       labels = c('-1', '0', '1'),
                       limits = c(-1,1)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = "black")

print(p)
```

[image]