# How to manually add legend item for geom_point in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a legend item for a `geom_point` layer in my plot (code below). The fire area legend works fine mapping the `size` aesthetic, but I cannot get the red Xs as a legend item. I am not trying to map the `shape` to any attribute, I rather want all to be the same shape and colour (hence not specifying inside `aes()`)

Any ideas? I feel like this should be an easy problem to solve but I cannot get it to work.

[image]

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = data.rf[1077:2152, ], 
             aes(x = mean_Tmean_Summer, 
                 y = mean_Precip_Summer),
             shape = 4,
             col = 'darkred',
             alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(data = data.rf[1:1076, ], 
             aes(x = mean_Tmean_Summer, 
                 y = mean_Precip_Summer,
                 size = fires$Fire_Ar),
                 alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size(name   = bquote("Fire Area "(m^2)),
             breaks = c(500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_viridis() +
  xlab("Mean Summer Temperature (°C)") +
  ylab("Mean Summer Precipitation (mm)")
```

Comment: I can give more specific answer if you give a dataset (analogue public) to use. As a short comment you probably may need to look into `scale_shape` that should be added after `scale_color_viridis`

Comment: As a general rule: If you want a legend, then you have to map on aesthetics, i.e. move `shape=4` inside aes. Then set your desired shape with `+ scale_shape_manual(values = 4)`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531787/add-a-single-point-to-legend-from-geom-point-and-scale-fill-gradient or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148679/construct-a-manual-legend-for-a-complicated-plot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496984/how-to-add-legend-to-ggplot-manually-r

Answer (score 0):

Just define the legend in manual scales like so:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- 1:10
y <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = T)
label <- c(rep("Interesting points", 10))

manual_shapes = c("Interesting points" = 4)
manual_colors = c("Interesting points" = "darkred")

data.frame(
  x = x,
  y = y,
  label = label 
) |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x, y, shape = label, col = label),
             alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    values = manual_shapes
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = manual_colors
  )
```

[image]